# Session timeout warning modal using react

Tags: reactjs, session-timeout, react-modal

I have a requirement to display timeout warning modal after 13 mins of inactivity and end session after 15 mins if user takes no action. I need to achieve this using reactjs. I checked react-timeout at https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-timeout#react-classic-verbose, but that didn't help.
If anyone knows of a way to do this, please share with me.

Comment: Off the top of my head, why not define an `active` property in the component's `state`.  Set a timeout via `setTimeout` to set the `active` to `false` after 13 minutes of inactivity.  Everytime the user moves the mouse / touches the screen, reset the timeout.  In the main app component, you can do something similar to end a session.

Answer (score 24):

You can create a higher order component like this and can pass child component through higher order component

HOC:

`// code

```
export default function(ComposedClass) {
  class AutoLogout extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        warningTime: 1000 * 60 * 10,
        signoutTime: 1000 * 60 * 15,
      };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      this.events = [
        'load',
        'mousemove',
        'mousedown',
        'click',
        'scroll',
        'keypress'
      ];

      for (var i in this.events) {
        window.addEventListener(this.events[i], this.resetTimeout);
      }

      this.setTimeout();
    }

    clearTimeoutFunc = () => {
      if (this.warnTimeout) clearTimeout(this.warnTimeout);

      if (this.logoutTimeout) clearTimeout(this.logoutTimeout);
    };

    setTimeout = () => {
      this.warnTimeout = setTimeout(this.warn, this.state.warningTime);
      this.logoutTimeout = setTimeout(this.logout, this.state.signoutTime);
    };

    resetTimeout = () => {
      this.clearTimeoutFunc();
      this.setTimeout();
    };

    warn = () => {
      window.alert("You will be logged out automatically in 1 minute")
      console.log('You will be logged out automatically in 1 minute.');
    };

    logout = () => {
      // Send a logout request to the API
      console.log('Sending a logout request to the API...');
      this.destroy();
    };

    destroy = () => {
     //clear the session
      browserHistory.push('/');
      window.location.assign('/');
    };

    render() {

      return (
        <div>
          <ComposedClass {...this.props} />
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
}
```

`

You can wrap this HOC to all those component in which you want to give user warning due to  inactivity, in routing file

`<Route path="/test" component={HOC(comonent)} />`

in above code component will be the page where you want to add this functionality.

Comment: Do you have a working example that demos something like this?

Comment: Doesn't an alert box halt the event loop, preventing the logout?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/3368818/j-woodchuck - did you get this work ?  If so, can you post your solution?

Comment: I am getting this:  Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Comment: how would I call a dispatch action from logout?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a full example of the modal idle warning.

Assuming you are using reactstrap for styling here is the example.

```js
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {Modal, ModalHeader, ModalBody, ModalFooter} from 'reactstrap';


function IdleMonitor()
{
  //Modal
  const [idleModal, setIdleModal] = useState(false);

  let idleTimeout = 1000 * 60 * 1;  //1 minute
  let idleLogout = 1000 * 60 * 2; //2 Minutes
  let idleEvent; 
  let idleLogoutEvent;

  /**
   * Add any other events listeners here
   */
  const events = [
    'mousemove',
    'click',
    'keypress'
  ];


  /**
   * @method sessionTimeout
   * This function is called with each event listener to set a timeout or clear a timeout.
   */
  const sessionTimeout = () => 
  {  
    if(!!idleEvent) clearTimeout(idleEvent);
    if(!!idleLogoutEvent) clearTimeout(idleLogoutEvent);

    idleEvent = setTimeout(() => setIdleModal(true), idleTimeout); //show session warning modal.
    idleLogoutEvent = setTimeout(() => logOut, idleLogout); //Call logged out on session expire.
  };

  /**
   * @method extendSession
   * This function will extend current user session.
   */
  const extendSession = () => 
  {
    console.log('user wants to stay logged in');
  }


  /**
   * @method logOut
   * This function will destroy current user session.
   */
  const logOut = () => 
  {
    console.log('logging out');
  }

  useEffect(() => 
  {
    for (let e in events) 
    {
      window.addEventListener(events[e], sessionTimeout);
    }

    return () => 
    {
      for(let e in events)
      {
        window.removeEventListener(events[e], sessionTimeout);
      }
    }
  },[]);


    return (

      <Modal isOpen={idleModal} toggle={() => setIdleModal(false)}>
        <ModalHeader toggle={() => setIdleModal(false)}>
            Session expire warning
        </ModalHeader>
        <ModalBody>
            your session will expire in {idleLogout / 60 / 1000} minutes. Do you want to extend the session?
        </ModalBody>
        <ModalFooter>
          <button className="btn btn-info"  onClick={()=> logOut()}>Logout</button>
          <button className="btn btn-success" onClick={()=> extendSession()}>Extend session</button>
        
        </ModalFooter>
      </Modal>
    )

  }

export default IdleMonitor;
```

after you create that class you can simply call it from anywhere like this

```
<IdleMonitor/>
```

don't forget to import it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to achieve same with Package, then you can write below code using React Idle Timer Package

> `npm i react-idle-timer`

```
import React from 'react'
import { useIdleTimer } from 'react-idle-timer'
import { useHistory } from 'react-router'

const SESSION_IDEL_MINUTES = 4;

const AutoLagoutTimer = (props: any) => {
    const { ComposedClass } = props
    const history = useHistory()

    const handleOnIdle = (event: any) => {
        // SHOW YOUR MODAL HERE AND LAGOUT
        console.log('user is idle', event)
        console.log('last active', getLastActiveTime())
        history.push("/lagout")
    }

    const {getLastActiveTime } = useIdleTimer({
        timeout: 1000 * 60 * SESSION_IDEL_MINUTES,
        onIdle: handleOnIdle,
        debounce: 500,
    })

    return <ComposedClass />
}

export default AutoLagoutTimer;
```

And for all your protected routes you can wrap with this component like below

```
     <Route path={"/dashboard"}>
        <AutoLagoutTimer ComposedClass={Dashboard} />
    </Route>
```